# Integrable and primitivable functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Recently we learned the fundamental theorem of calculus and subsequently Leibniz-Newton formula, that linked the primitive with the definite integral.
I know that Leibniz-Newton can be applied when the funcition is both integrable and primitivable, but not necessarily continuous. This led to the drawing below. Although I can easily find examples of functions that are only integrable and not primitivable and in the comments there is allready a function that is only primitivable and not integrable, i cannot seem to find a function that is both integrable and primitivable but not continuous.

- Could you find such a function?

[Here is a depiction of the inclusion I've been shown in class.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hETp.jpg)

Comment: The term "primitivable" is not widely used. Can you confirm that a function $f\colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ is "primitivable" if there is a differentiable function $F \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\in I$ (where $I$ is some interval in $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: Yes. Luckily I found one example in one book.

Comment: If you take "integrable" as "properly Riemann integrable", something like $x^2 \sin x^{-2}$ gives you an example. The derivative is unbounded near $0$, so not properly Riemann integrable. It is however improperly Riemann integrable. If you want to avoid that, you have to put in some more work.

Comment: No, your example is just what I asked for. My class doesn't specify at all the difference between proper and improper Riemann integrals.

Comment: I had some questions where the answer was given to me in the comment section. Why is that?

Comment: Could be that one isn't sure whether it does really answer the question. In other cases, one is too lazy to write a real answer and just drops a short comment.

Comment: What is a proper and an improper Riemann integral? Be my teacher please.

Comment: I guess what you learned as the Riemann integral is the proper Riemann integral. If $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function, and there is a number $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all partitions $a = x_0 < x_1 < \dotsc < x_n = b$ of $[a,b]$ whose mesh $\max \{ x_i - x_{i-1} : 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\}$ is smaller than $\delta$ and all choices of points $\xi_i\in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ you have $$\Biggl\lvert s - \sum_{i = 1}^n f(\xi_i)\cdot (x_i-x_{i-1}) \Biggr\rvert<\varepsilon,$$ then $f$ is (properly) Riemann-integrable …

Comment: and $s$ is the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$, $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = s.$$ A proper Riemann integral is over an interval $[a,b]$ with $-\infty < a \leqslant b < +\infty$, and the integrand must be bounded. Improper Riemann integrals extend the notion of integrability to intervals with end points at infinity (one or both), like $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx = \pi,$$ or to unbounded integrands, like $1/\sqrt{x}$, by looking at the behaviour of the proper Riemann integrals $$\int_u^v f(x)\,dx$$ as the integral limits tend to the interesting points, e.g.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\,dx := \lim_{R\to +\infty} \int_0^R f(x)\,dx + \lim_{S\to -\infty} \int_S^0 f(x)\,dx$$ if those limits exist (and $f$ is properly Riemann-integrable on all bounded intervals). And $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx := \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \int_{\varepsilon}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$ is the improper Riemann integral of the unbounded function $f\colon (0,1] \to \mathbb{R},\; x \mapsto 1/\sqrt{x}$ over the interval $(0,1]$. Nothing deep.

Comment: And for the example above, the derivative is properly Riemann-integrable over every interval $[\varepsilon,1]$ with $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, and the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$ of the integrals exists, so it's improperly Riemann-integrable. But not properly, since it's unbounded.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot.